# C - how to store XML string and keep formatting?

Tags: c, xml, formatting, printf, string-formatting

I have the following string and I need to keep formatting, indents, linebreaks etc. Any idea how to do that?

```
char *myXMLString = 
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
"<painting>"
"   <img src=\"madonna.jpg\" alt=\"Foligno Madonna, by Raphael\"/>"
"   <caption>MY_REPLACED_TEXT"
"   <date>1511</date>-<date>1512</date>.</caption>"
"</painting>";
```

printf just gives one long tine of text.

Answer (score 2):

add `"\n"` where you see it appropriate, e.g.:

```
char *myXMLString = 
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" "\n"
"<painting>\n"
"   <img src=\"madonna.jpg\" alt=\"Foligno Madonna, by Raphael\"/>" "\n"
"   <caption>MY_REPLACED_TEXT\n"
"   <date>1511</date>-<date>1512</date>.</caption>\n"
"</painting>\n";
```